# @font-face works bad in windows (with firefox chrome ie) works fine in Ubuntu

Tags: css, font-face

here my problem: the font Fedra looks orrible with @font-face in windows, I don't know why. It looks fine in Ubuntu.

You can see this [here](http://www.pierluigiballatore.com/htsun_sito/)

What's the problem?

Here the code css

```
 @font-face
 {
      font-family: Fedra Sans;
      src: url('../font/FEDRAS01.eot'); /*For IE 6+*/
      src: url('../font/FEDSAB01.ttf');
 }
 @font-face
 {
      font-family: Fedra Sans;
          src: url('../font/FEDRASAM.eot'); 
          src: url('../font/FEDRASAM.ttf');
      font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "works bad"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ttf and eot fonts are not enough for successfully embedding fonts on the web. Read here: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax
and here:
http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax

Then you can try and create the @font-face kit using http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Windows doesn't render fonts the same as other operating systems.

You can try using images, [sIFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement) or [Cufon](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/)/similar.